# What is the type of the wifi interference to ZigBee? Multiplicative or additive?

Tags: signal, noise, interference

As we all know, the cross technology interference is a critical problem. CTI means that different communication technologies operate on the same spectrum (e.g., 2.4GHz), and this would lead to the critical interference problem. There are lots of works study the interference on ZigBee[1].

Now, I have the question that 
"What is the type of the wifi interference to ZigBee? Multiplicative or additive?".

Because of the different interfering type, the different filtering methods would be utilized. [2]

[1]Understanding the Impact of Cross Technology Interference on IEEE 802.15.4
[2]https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-additive-and-multiplicative-noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the two RF sources are not synchronized, by default they are additive, and random to each other. I might add that cell-phones and cordless phones operate in the same frequency bands. That is why cordless phones usually have a channel switch option if you have interference.
 For WiFi and cell phones that might have close or same channels, the ID code of the device is used to separate and identify them so they only respond to data meant for them. Remember that smart phones and cell towers can detect "crowding" of any band and request another channel or tower, including local WiFi (handled by the smart phone or tablet). 
ZigBee does not have much power or self awareness if it is using a crowded channel, *and could be swamped out*. ZigBee is best used with a line-of-sight antenna over short range. Add-on software to select the most quiet band is recommended. ZigBee also has a 915MHZ band but the data rate is slower.
**NOTE:** All of these communication types use data encryption so if severe interference or snooping occurs any data or voice sent cannot be deciphered.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. There still one questions that I am not clear from your answer. What is the exact definition of "synchronized"? Is it mean that different modulation technologies can not synchronized and then the interference among different   modulation technologies is additive? And the same technologies interfered may be multiplicative by chance? Thanks!

Comment: Any 'multiplicative' spikes would be random and rare. By 'synchronized' I mean they share a common clock source. That is normally used for antenna arrays that use the exact same channel. The overall effect multiplies the wave energy such that it's much stronger radiant energy. Antenna's must be 2 wavelengths apart.